# Implementing a roling scribe list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I got the admin rights to build a team Sharepoint site, but don't own the main site. To rotate the minute taking of the weekly team meeting, I'd like to introduce a list with the 6 team members and a start date. Then I'd like the list to automatically update the next in the row to the next meeting date (start date + 7d). Currently I calculate the next two weeks within Excel and copy the dates into the list items row... :-(

1. can I realize this by some trick in the list item of Sharepoint without additional programms?
2. If not, how could I implement for example a c# tool with the given functionality into my site?
3. Is the SharePoint Designer necessary for the realization?

I thank you for any help on this, as I am just starting to dive into this matter and willing to learn more ;-)

BR

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calendar list and add 6 recurring events, one for each team member. Pick the initial start dates for each event (that is, the first days for which each team member will be responsible for taking notes), tell it how often you want it to recur (for example, every 6 weeks), and then you can use your calendar to track who's responsible for a given week.

[image: screenshot of Recurrence field on an Event item]

Comment: I tried the calendar item within my team, thanks. It didn't occur to me as a possibility. The only thing that was uncomfortable is to change out two dates when one goes into vacation. This was quite easy in the list but I still like it very much.